# How to get Node.Js to allow me to provide client cert with smart card/cac

Tags: node.js, https, smartcard, cac, cacerts

I am trying to build a CAC authentication system using node.js but am having trouble.  I followed a few tutorials regarding setting up a https server and I can get that to work just fine; however, using the logic below, whenever I access my server:

```
https://localhost:3000
```

I am prompted to login with the auth button that is sent from the "/" route handler; however, it immediately defaults to the else clause:

```
res.status(401)
        .send(`Sorry, but you need to provide a client certificate to continue.`)
```

Normally, when accessing a cac-enabled site, I a prompted to choose a smart card certificate, which allows me to login; however, in this case, I am not being prompted at all.

I found a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017130/how-to-authenticate-user-with-cac-in-node-express) but was not able to get anything to work from the article they referenced.    They mentioned that I would have to set my 'ca' property on the https server to allow the specific CA of the CAC in question.  I used my browser to locate my CAC certificates and exported my certificates and put them in the approved CA list but I still do not get any prompt.

I was initially using `req.connection.getPeerCertificate()` to prompt for certificates; however, I read that req.connection was deprecated in my verison of Node.JS (14.15.0) so I have also tried `req.socket.getPeerCertificate()`.  The server seems to run just fine either way and I get no errors client-side or server-side (with exception to the 401 response that is sent from the server since it is not getting a valid certificate).  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')

// Https options
const options = {
    // Path to private key (created by openssl in createSelfSignedCert.bat)
    key: fs.readFileSync('server_key.pem')
    // Path to public key
    ,cert: fs.readFileSync('server_cert.pem')
    // Indicate that https server should request client certificates
    ,requestCert: true
    // Manually handle bad requests (no certs)
    ,rejectUnauthorized: false
    //List of accepted/valid CA certs - just our own for now
    ,ca: [ 
        fs.readFileSync('server_cert.pem')
        ,fs.readFileSync('cac52.cer')
        ,fs.readFileSync('cac_export.p7b')
    ]
    //,ca: .
}


// Use express for routing
const app = express()


// Unprotected public endpoint
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<a href="login">Auth</a>')
})


// Protected endpoint
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    // req.connection is deprecated, perhaps req.socket.getPeerCertificate()
    const cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate()
    //const cert = req.socket.getPeerCertificate()


    if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.send(`Hello ${cert.subject.CN}, your certificate was issued by ${cert.issuer.CN}!`)
        console.log(`${cert}`)
    } else if (cert.subject) {
        res.status(403)
           .send(`Sorry ${cert.subject.CN}, certificates from ${cert.issuer.CN} are not welcome here.`)
           console.log(`${cert}`)
    } else {
        res.status(401)
            .send(`Sorry, but you need to provide a client certificate to continue.`)
    }

})

// Create https server with options and app routes
https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by changing this setting in my browser (Chrome):

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

I got that from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900210/10905433). I think Chrome was not prompting me to choose a certificate because it was treating my dev environment as insecure. After I enabled that setting, the certificate prompt appeared as expected and the '/login' URL displayed the CN of the cert I chose.

Also, you'll need to make sure you have the correct CA's. AFAIK you cannot just export a CA certificate chain from your CAC - you need to have them provided to you from the CA. If you're working on a DoD project, you'll need the DoD Root CA's. If you already have a DoD CAC, you can get the DoD Root CA's from [this link](https://cyber.mil/pki-pke/admins/).

Remember, the certificates loaded on your CAC are *client* certificates, they are unique to you. The CA (Certifying Authority) is the organization that *issued* you those certificates. When you add the CA cert(s) to your project, what your app is effectively saying is "I can accept client certs *issued by* this CA."